# Tamely Ramified field extension of a Local Field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, local-field, kummer-theory

Let $K= (K, m)$ be a local field (therefore a *complete, non-archimedian field with discrete valuation* $v: K \to \mathbb{Z} \cup \{ \infty \}$)  with *perfect resudue field* $k$ of characteristic $p \ge 0$.

Assume $L/K$ is a *finite* field extension of degree $n=[L:K]$ which is assumed to be *tamely ramified* (i.e. $e:= e(L/K)$ is prime to characteristic $p$). Additionally assume $K$ contains *all* $n$-roots $\zeta^i _n$ with $0 \le i < n$.

recall $e$ is defined as unique number $m_L^e = m_K O_L$.

I want to show that $L/K$ is cyclic, i.e. $Gal(L/K) = \mathbb{Z}/n$.

My attempts: I want to use Kummer theory. Thus I have to show that $K$ contains all $n$-th roots (this was the assumption), the extension has the form $L= K(a)$ with $a$ root of minimal polynomial $X^n -c$ with $c \in K $.

does anybody have an idea how to manage it?

Comment: Is $L/K$ cyclic with $K=\Bbb{F}_5((X)), L = K(X^{1/2},\zeta_{24})$ ? To see if it is abelian: from $\pi_L^e = \pi_K u$ and $\zeta_e \in L$ and the binomial series you have $\pi_K^{1/e} \in L$ and $(\pi_L) = (\pi_K^{1/e})$, the remaining part of the extension is unramified.

Comment: sorry, I confused a neccessary assumption: I assume that $K$ contains all $n$-roots! excuse

Comment: this is what I want to prove

Comment: I gave a particular example of $L/K$. Is it cyclic ?

Comment: no, since $\zeta_{24} \not \in K$ by hensel's lemma! this is a nice conterexample. thank you!

Comment: it's $n =[L:K]=2* deg(\Phi_{24})=16$

Comment: ...but this confuses me. in your example $K$ doesn't contain $16=n$th roots again by hensel's lemma, therefore this cannot be used as a conterexample. do I have overlooked something?

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_5(\zeta_{24}) = ?$

Comment: Why would $L/K$ be Galois in the first place? Kummer theory does not apply unless we know that.

Comment: But reuns gave you an example of a degree four extension with the Klein four as the Galois group.

Comment: why reuns' example is a degree four extension? the core problem is to determine the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{24}$ over $\Bbb{F}_5$. over $\Bbb{Q}$ that's the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{24}(z)= z^8-x^4+1$. I don't know any conceptial strategy to determine the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{24}$ over $\Bbb{F}_5$. obviously it  divides $\Phi_{24}(z)$ but why it has degree $2$? do you know a standard strategy or theorems which help to deal with calculations of minimal polynomials of $\zeta_k$ over finite fields $\Bbb{F}_d$?

Comment: ...I think I have the answer for degree $n$: $\Phi_{24}$ splits into a product of irreducible
factors, all of the same degree $d$, where $d$ is the order of $5$ modulo $24$, therefore indeed $2$. the extension $K(\zeta_{24}) \to K(\zeta_{24},X^{1/2})$ has also degree $2$, therefore I understand why $K \to L$ has degree $4$. observe that $K$ contains the $5-1=4$the roots, therefore the assumption on the root hold. is the extension Galois?

Comment: Because $x^{p^k-1}-1\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ has at most $p^k-1$ roots in the algebraic closure, $\Bbb{F}_{p^k} $ is the splitting field of $x^{p^k-1}-1$ but not of $x^d-1,d<p^k-1$, thus $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}^*$ is cyclic with $p^k-1$ element and $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}=\Bbb{F}_p(\zeta_{p^k -1})$.

Comment: I see no obstructions that the same argument goes through for $K=\Bbb{F}_p((X))$ from your conterexample, i.e. $\Bbb{F}_p((X))(\zeta_{24})$ is Galois over $\Bbb{F}_p((X))$ and obviously $L = K(X^{1/2},\zeta_{24})$ is Galois over $\Bbb{F}_p((X))(\zeta_{24})$.

Comment: Good job finally spotting that $\Bbb{F}_5(\zeta_{24})=\Bbb{F}_{25}$. I was worried for a moment :-)

Comment: It works almost the same way with all primes $p>3$ for then we have $24\mid p^2-1$. An exception is when $p\equiv1\pmod{24}$, for then adjoining a 24th root of unity won't do anything. Do you agree that with $K=\Bbb{F}_p((x))$ the extension $L=\Bbb{F}_{p^2}((x))(\sqrt{x})$ is Galois over $K$ with Galois group the Klein four?

Comment: yes, a composition of Galois extension is again Galois. Thank you both!